# Live migration (to other host) of ROS 2 nodes: supported?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to specify a ROS2 component (node) by some method such as PID and migrate the node to a server or computer with another ROS2 environment in the default function or in the provided library that can be included / imported?

I wanna realize live migration of ROS2 node, but I would like to implement it with the function provided by ROS2 as much as possible.

I'm using foxy in my environment, so please let me know if you have a similar implementation in a similar version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365253/live-migration-(to-other-host)-of-ros-2-nodes:-supported?/) by [hamstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/63011/hamstick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I wanna realize live migration of ROS2 node, but I would like to implement it with the function provided by ROS2 as much as possible.

This is (currently) not supported.

And personally, I'm also not sure whether this should be something ROS should do at all.

Managing state like this and migrating running processes to other hosts is quite complex. There are solutions to this in the form of technology stacks like k8s and similar platforms and we should probably use those, instead of integrating something like it in ROS proper.

It's not migration yet, but there are some people looking into deploying ROS 2 applications onto/using kubernetes. See [ROS 2 on Kubernetes](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-2-on-kubernetes/17182) and the earlier [Robotics Distributed System based on Kubernetes](https://discourse.ros.org/t/robotics-distributed-system-based-on-kubernetes/12558) on ROS Discourse.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hamstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/63011/hamstick/) on 2020-11-15**:
Thank you so much.
The configuration of ROS2 + Kebernetes has many introductions such as how to do it just by searching lightly on the internet.
I would like to take a closer look at the implementation.